# IIS/Javascript SPA reload page if javascript files were updated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, browser-cache

I have a single page application in Angular and ASP.Net hosted in IIS, I think for other languages it might be the same. Now when a user is inside the application and I updated the server with a new version, the user session ends and he is redirected to the login page. Now the problem is that the JS files changed (I am adding also an additional version-string to the JS filename) but because the page did not reload/refresh (SPA), the JS files are not updated and the user will login and work with the old files untill he reloads the browser or closes it.
Is there any way to tell the browser that the files are changed?

Comment: In my applications I have to time sessions out anyway, which shows a page with a link that does a hard reload of the SPA frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you want to let the browser know the file has changed, you could write a Angular component make an ajax request with current js version to your server for some while. If the server's js has updated, then you could return the updated response to the client.

If the client receive the update response, you could inform the end-user that a new version will be loaded and ask them if they wish to save the work and then reload etc.